# Printing list of diverse objects

Tags: c#, collections, polymorphism

I am trying to return a combine list of two different list types. Where all child class is derived from same base class which doesn't have any code.
I can see the items in base class. But, now what it supposed to have.

```
class BaseClass
{
   //empty no code
}
class ChildClassA : BaseClass
{

     public string Name {get; set;}
     public DateTime DateAccess {get; set;}

     public ChildClassA(string name, DateTime dateAccess){
        Name = name; 
        DateAccess = dateAccess;
     }


     public List<ChildClassA> GetListMethod()
     {
       //block of code

       return List<ChildClassA>;  // each items have Name and DateAccess
     }

}

class ChildClassB: BaseClass
{

     public string Group {get; set;}
     public DateTime SessionDuration {get; set;}
     public string Report{get; set;}

     public ChildClassB(string group, DateTime sessionDuration, string report)
     {
        Group = group; 
        SessionDuration = sessionDuration;
        Report = report; 
     }


   public List<ChildClassB> GetListMethod()
   {
     //block of code

    return List<ChildClassB>;   // each item has Group, SessionDuration and Report
   }
}

class CombineListClass
{
    public List<BaseClass> GetCombineList()
    {

        List<BaseClass> listFromBaseClass = new List<BaseClass>();

        ChildClassA a = new ChildClassA(); 
        var listFromA = a.GetListMethod();

        ChildClassB b = new ChildClassB(); 
        var listFromB = b.GetListMethod();

        listFromBaseClass.AddRange(listFromA);
        listFromBaseClass.AddRange(listFromB);

        foreach(var item in listFromBaseClass)
        {

           //print the item from each listFromBaseClass
           // needs to print Name, DateAccess, Group, SessionDuration, Report in one output file.

        }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check object type using "is" keyword and cast it and display respectively proper values:

```
 foreach(var item in listFromBaseClass)
    {

       //print the item from each listFromBaseClass
       // needs to print Name, DateAccess, Group, SessionDuration, Report in one output file.
        if (item is ChildClassA)
        {
              Console.WriteLine(((ChildClassA)item).Name);
        }
        else if (item is ChildClassB)
        {
              Console.WriteLine(((ChildClassB)item).Group);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Przemyslaw, 
Now what if ? If I want to print whole list in time order fashion of both DateTime DateAccess and DateTime SessionDuration. 
Right now, first it will print all the items from ChildClassA and then items from ChildClassB.

Is There a way, to have mixed items from both child classes and order them by DateTime ?

Comment: But if those dates have different meaning then its strange to mix them in ordering. Anyway to achieve this you should either move the DateTime property to base class, declare an interface which has DateTime property and make the common collection to by of type of this interface or if you want to leave everything as is you can use such trick: listFromBaseClass = listFromBaseClass.OrderBy(i=>i is ChildClassA ? ((ChildClassA)i).DateAccess : ((ChildClassB)i).SessionDuration).ToList(); in this way you order by two different fields depending on object type.

Answer (score 3):

You could have them each implement an interface: IReportable

```
interface IReportable
{
    Row GenerateReportRow();
}

class ChildClassA : IReportable
{
    Row GenerateReportRow()
    {
        //whatever important items
    }
}
```

Then you can leverage the magic of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

```
foreach(var item in listFromBaseClass)
{
   item.GenerateReportRow();
}
```

Otherwise you could just have a collection of Objects if they don't really share anything other than wanting to store them all in the same place.

Comment: This is the better answer. When you have a choice between conditionally checking types and polymorphism, always choose polymorphism.